# Spring Boot auto configuration of Kafka Producers with multiple De-Serializer types

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am trying to configure KafkaTemplate in my spring boot applications. I am able to make it work when all the Kafka producers are using the same serializer/de-serializer class.

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Now I have a requirement for one of the producers to have a different value serializer. How do I achieve this? I tried creating a custom bean for that particular template, but that breaks the other auto-wirings.

I am using v2.4.1